# How to reload a one page document with sections in javascript on click

Tags: javascript

The question is almost everywhere on the Internet, but none of the snippets I found are working. What I'm looking is a simple way to reload a link in JavaScript (on click).

I'm on: page.com/#feed
I need to go to page.com/#news

The whole content is loaded once because it's a one page website.
Then, I need to go to #news and immediately reload it... is it possible?

Comment: it kind of defeats the purpose of a one page application, having to reload it. Why do you need to reload it after going to the url?

Comment: Because I have a javascript on #news that only triggers when the page had loaded. Is there a way to do that please?

Comment: Are you using a framework? If not you could trigger it when you click on the link to go to news?

Comment: Don't have framework... I can only use onclick because I'm on Carrd.co

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JavaScripts [location.reload()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) function

Comment: I already looked into it. It only reloads the main page not the target..
I also wanted to use on click with that: `window.location.assign("https://www.website.com/#news");` but It only reload the current page... still not the target page as I need.

Comment: @Incoming I guess I don't understand how your page is laid out... Maybe You can try using links to navigate to mypage/#news and if you still need reloading use onload event to trigger reload then

Comment: Is there a way to tell javascript to trigger on load only if I go to a specific url?

Comment: @Incoming Yes, you can get the url using location.href